# Data frame index

Tags: python, arcpy, data-frame

Can anyone know how to make index ,in arcpy, for a several data frame in  one mxd?
That question related to this question : [Insert layer file to specific data frame](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/121550/insert-layer-file-to-specific-data-frame)

Answer (score 2):

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Transportation")[0]
```

Where [0] refers to the order of the data frame you are looking for. More info: [DataFrame (arcpy.mapping)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s300000003000000)